# Database design for hundred of tables

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I have been using MySQL for almost all my application that I developed. Now there's a new application that I need to develop with the following UI (web based)

```
Table 1 (col1, col2,col3,col4)
Table 2 (col1, col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
Table 3 (col1, col2)
...
Table 500 (col1, col2,col3,col4,col5,col6, col7)
```

Basically the number of tables can reach up to 500 (or even 1000). My question is, should I still use MySQL for this ? Will NoSQL be more appropriate for this ?

**Why do I need this ?**

I'd like to know if there's such mechanism to create `tables` on the fly without knowing exactly how many tables will be there. If I have to use MySQL, then traditionally I need to know exactly how many tables I want to create, create them and finally start the development.

I am thinking of creating something like Wikipedia. Not the Wikipedia itself, but from one content to another I can see different set of sections thus I'd like to follow this concept.

Comment: I hope you don't create tables dynamically per user or per date

Comment: You should, first of all, explain why you would need such a thing.

Comment: @lad2025, by default theres only one record for each table. But once a user edits the record, he or she will have the customized record which he or she alone can see.

Comment: @abiieez For me it sounds like very poor design. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl

Comment: @lad2025, Any better design you can suggest ? Can I just use two tables in the db ?

Comment: If you have 500 or 1000 tables that contain only one record and need to create them on the fly, there is a mistake in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per op comment: "by default theres only one record for each table. But once a user edits the record, he or she will have the customized record which he or she alone can see"

That may explain why you have hundreds of tables. You can also have **1 table max** in your system that only the authorized user can see his or her row.

The reason you probably don't elaborate is because the schema is so poorly designed that it is best to be silent on the 2nd comment posted above that asked "You should, first of all, explain why you would need such a thing."

Comment: Yes after reading the comments and your answer I realized that the schema needs to be redesigned completely. In the end, I am going with 2 tables. `Table` and `TableColumn`. Thanks.

Comment: well let me know if I can help with something else some day. That was an awful way to earn 25 points :)

Comment: All I needed was an answer or some correction on the design. I am glad I did :)